# Need help finding my deleted question which had a link to a helpful question/answer

Tags: discussion

This needs to go on meta I think but as I don't have enough rep for that I'm just gonna ask that if you can, please migrate this to meta. Also the tag was just randomly chosen so this could be posted, sorry bout that.

I asked a question a long while ago, which is now deleted. It's not in the recently deleted, and it was about putting blender on a raspberry pi 4. It was closed for being a duplicate of another question that had steps for installing blender on a pi. It's the only question I've asked so far so if you can see deleted questions just check my question page please and then answer with the question it was called a duplicate of. Thanks!

Comment: You have 101 rep on main site, I would expect to carry onto meta as the 101 is the association rep from the network. I would expect you should be able to post on meta without migrating the post, but either way, this will end up migrated eventually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your deleted questions show up in [your user profile](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/current) under [Questions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=questions).

I assume you mean https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193193/will-blender-run-well-on-my-raspberry-pi

Comment: yes thank you. for whatever reason, it does not show up on my question page tho which is weird.

Comment: At the bottom of your questions page is "Recently Deleted Questions" link. It will show any of your questions deleted in the last 60 (IIRC) days.